# Why does the Laplace Transform not solve this

Tags: trigonometry, laplace-transform

Suppose I have an equation like:

$\sin t=t\cos t$

If I take the Laplace transform of both sides I obtain:

$\frac{1}{s^2+1}=\frac{s^2-1}{(s^2+1)^2}$

Simplifying I obtain:

$\frac{s^2-1}{s^2+1}=1$

Taking the inverse laplace transform:

$ \delta(t)-2 \sin t = \delta(t) $

$ \sin t = 0 $

Apart from the solution $t=0$, this method does not yield the correct solution.

So my question is this:

Is this method a valid way to approach the problem, or is there a fundamental flaw with this approach?

Comment: Is there some reason you are trying to solve a trancendental equation with a laplace transform? Usually you use that on differential equations

Comment: If an equation holds for all values of the variable you can take Laplace transform on both sides. The very idea of taking Laplace transform to find values of t for which $\sin t = t \cos t$ is wrong.